# Calculate the Fundamental Group of a Set $\;X=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 2x^2-11xy-2y^2=0 \big\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am starting to study fundamental groups and came across the following result:

Let be $\;X=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 2x^2-11xy-2y^2=0 \big\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

I Have to calculate the $\,\pi_1(X)\,$ of a set $X$.

I solved the second grade equation by the y and I created the  3 sets :

$\;X_1=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: y=-\frac{(11-\sqrt{137})}{4}x\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ $\bigcup$ $\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: y=-\frac{(11+\sqrt{137})}{4}x,x>0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

$\;X_2=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: y=-\frac{(11+\sqrt{137})}{4}x\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ .

$\;X_1\cap\;X_2 =\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: y=-\frac{(11-\sqrt{137})}{4}x, x>0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

We can use the Saifert-Van Kampen Theorem to say that
$\,\pi_1(X_1)\,$ is trivial (because $\;X_1$ is contractible  to a point) ,the same for  $\,\pi_1(X_2)\,$ and $\,\pi_1(X_2\cap X_1)\,$ .

Then $\,\pi_1(X) \simeq \dfrac{ \pi_1(X_1)\ast\pi_1(X_2) } {\mathit{H}} = \dfrac{\{\emptyset\}\ast\{\emptyset\}}{\{\emptyset\}}=\{\emptyset\} ,$

I do not know if my solution is right.
Can someone tell me if is it the right answer?

Comment: $X$ itself is contractible. No need to use van Kampen.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is correct. However, in this case there is an easier way of doing it; namely, by showing your space is actually contractible.

Indeed, note
$$2x^2-11xy-y^2=2\left(\left(x-\frac{11}{4}y\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{137}}{4}y\right)^2\right).$$

Therefore, if you consider the homeomorphism $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2; h(x,y)=\left(x-\frac{11}{4}y,\frac{\sqrt{137}}{4}y\right)$, you get
$$X \cong h(X)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x^2-y^2=0\} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x = y \} \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x = -y \}.$$
Therefore, $X$ is homeomorphic to the union of the diagonals of the coordinate plane. The latter is clearly contractible, and hence, so is $X$. In particular, $\pi_1(X,\cdot)=\{1\}$.

**Remark.** Be careful! There are no empty groups (they all have an identity). A trivial group is the group with only one element; namely, the identity.